# Deleting queued jobs in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd

I have added some jobs to a queue in Laravel. However, I forgot to put `$job->delete()` in the function and there is an error in my function.  This means the job is never ending.  It keeps going being replaced onto the queue and keeps erroring in my log file. How can I delete it from the command line?

I am using `beanstalkd` for my queuing.

Comment: Beanstalkd, right? (f is next to d on the keyboard...)

Comment: For future designs, you might be interested in this approach that works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696817/470749

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Restart Beanstalk. On Ubuntu:

```
sudo service beanstalkd restart
```

Comment: this works only if the beanstalkd service is running in memory, but if `wal` directory is on the disk then even restarting the beanstalkd service won't work. On the other hand even if this works in command line, it will be too ugly to implement inside the code

Answer (score 34):

I am using Redis instead of Beanstalkd but this should be the same in both. Restarting Redis doesn't solve the problem. I looked at `RedisQueues` in the [Laravel 4.2 API Docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/) and found:

```
public Job|null pop(string $queue = null)
  //Pop the next job off of the queue.
```

This is the same if you look at `BeanstalkedQueue`.

I threw it in `app/routes.php` inside dd*, loaded that page and voila.

```
Route::get('/', function() {
  dd(Queue::pop());
  #return View::make('hello');
});
```

**NOTE:** Reload the page once per queue.

The queue was pulled off the stack. I would like to see a cleaner solution but this worked for me more than once.

**dd($var) = Laravel's die and dump function = die(var_dump($var))*

**Edit 1:** *For Redis*

The above obviously isn't the best solution so here is a better way. Be careful!

> FLUSHDB - Delete all the keys of the currently selected DB. This command never fails.

For Redis use [FLUSHDB](http://redis.io/commands/FLUSHDB). This will flush the Redis database not Laravel's database. In the terminal:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> FLUSHDB
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

Comment: +1 FLUSHDB is the only thing that worked for me. Had a method call i spelt wrong, once i corrected it, it just wouldn't stop calling the incorrect one. Found this and it worked :)

Comment: Useful Related Blog :
https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-delete-queued-jobs-using-redis-horizon-artisan-command-47c3527024e0

Answer (score 2):

I made an artisan command which will clear all the jobs in your queue. You can optionally specify the connection and/or the pipe.

https://github.com/morrislaptop/laravel-queue-clear

Answer (score 2):

**Important note: This solution works only for beanstalk**

## There are two solutions:

### 1- From Your PHP Code

To delete jobs programatically, you can do this:

```
    //Que the job first. (YourJobProcessor is a class that has a method called fire like `fire($job,$data)`
    $res = Queue::later(5, YourJobProcessor::class, $data, 'queue_name');
    //get the job from the que that you just pushed it to
    $job = Queue::getPheanstalk()->useTube("queue_name")->peek($res);
    //get the job from the que that you just pushed it to
    $res = Queue::getPheanstalk()->useTube("queue_name")->delete($job);
```

If everything went good, the job will not execute, else the job will execute after 5 seconds

### 2- From Command Line (Linux and Mac only)

From command line (In linux and mac) you can use  [`beanstool`](https://github.com/src-d/beanstool).

For example, if you want to delete 100 ready jobs from the `queue_name` tube you can do the following:

```
  for i in {1..100}; do beanstool delete -t queue_name --state=ready; done
```

Answer (score 1):

For Redis users, instead of flushing, using redis-cli I ran this command:

```
KEYS *queue*
```

on the Redis instance holding queued jobs,
then deleted whatever keys in the response

```
DEL queues:default queues:default:reserved
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my case

Answer (score 0):

Only way I could do it was to restart my computer.  Could not find a way to delete a job.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this php-based web admin console](http://mnapoli.fr/phpBeanstalkdAdmin/) in the past.

Otherwise, I believe you'll find yourself using Terminal + telnet, altho I can't find any documentation for deleting via telnet (Just viewing a list of jobs in queue).

It seems that most articles tell you to [use your code+library of choice and loop around queues jobs](http://www.sitepoint.com/giant-killing-with-beanstalkd/) to delete them in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Laravel 5.1 compatible [command](https://gist.github.com/cheelahim/ded1ab9e5e9a290fe9fc), which allows you to clear Beanstalkd queue. The command takes queue name as argument ('default' by default). Do not forget to register it in app/Console/Kernel.php