# Laravel Notifications - delay email sending and cancel if condition met

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

I have an app where I am sending a push notification which is fine if the user is logged into the application - however, if they're not / if they have not read the notification within X minutes I'd like to send them an email.

The way I am going about this is to use Laravel Notifications to create a mail, broadcast & database notification. On the `toMail()` method I'm returning a mailable with a delay -

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new \App\Mail\Order\NewOrder($this->order))
        ->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
}
```

After the minutes are up, the email will send **but**, before the send goes ahead I'd like to perform a check to see if the push/database notification has already been marked as read and if it has cancel the email send. The only way I can think to do this is to bind to the `MessageSending` event that is baked into Laravel -

```
// listen for emails being sent
'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
    'App\Listeners\Notification\SendingEmail'
],
```

The only problem is this listener receives a Swift mail event and not the original mailable I was dispatching so I don't know how to cancel it. Any ideas and thanks in advance?

Comment: take a look at "Queues" https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel queued job in Laravel or Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255735/how-to-cancel-queued-job-in-laravel-or-redis)

Comment: Sounds like you should not be dispatching the mailable but dispatching a job that handles the mailable.

Comment: @Devon - perhaps you are right - just feels like a very complex way of sending out an email. I'll take a look!

Comment: take look at https://medium.com/@hotmeteor/handling-delayed-notifications-in-laravel-b6699ec30649

Comment: @ilyar that was exactly what I'm looking for! Put it down as an answer and I'll mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class extends Notification

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    if($this->dontSend($notifiable)) {
        return [];
    }
    return ['mail'];
}

public function dontSend($notifiable)
{
    return $this->appointment->status === 'cancelled';
}
```

Class EventServiceProvider

```
protected $listen = [
    NotificationSending::class => [
        NotificationSendingListener::class,
    ],
];
```

Class NotificationSendingListener

```
public function handle(NotificationSending $event)
{
    if (method_exists($event->notification, 'dontSend')) {
        return !$event->notification->dontSend($event->notifiable);
    }
    return true;
}
```

For more details look article [Handling delayed notifications in Laravel](https://medium.com/@hotmeteor/handling-delayed-notifications-in-laravel-b6699ec30649)

Comment: This is not working, perhaps it did however dontsend is not being checked once in the queue